# AutoMapper Map KeyValuePair<String, String> to Class?

Tags: automapper

What I am trying to do is take a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String, String>>` and map them to a class.

So I want to take those `KeyValuePair<String, String>` and map them as the property name and value to a class.

Can this be done? Or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it can be done, for instance like this

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<KeyValuePair<string, string>, MyClass>()
       .ConstructUsing(x => new MyClass { Name = x.Key, Value = x.Value });

    var kv = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Key", "Val");
    var mapped = Mapper.Map<KeyValuePair<String, String>, MyClass>(kv);

    Console.WriteLine(mapped.ToString());

    Console.ReadLine();
}
    
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Name : {0}, Value : {1}", Name, Value);
    }
}
```

use Lists in create mapping in case you want to deal with IEnumerable